# How to create this type of C++ template array collection class with `constexpr` Compatible Instantiation

Tags: c++, class, templates, instantiation, constexpr

I'm wondering if it is possible on a C++ project to create a template class that allows for instantiating arrays with variable sizes, similar to the following example:

```cpp
ArraysCollection<int, 3, 6, 8, 2> myArrays;
```

In this example, `myArrays` should contain arrays of different sizes, and the user can input as many sizes they want to have in the template arguments. I would also like to ensure that the class is `constexpr` compatible. The resulting data members of the class should be something like:

```cpp
SomeType arraysCollectionData[] = {
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0}
}
```

Another example:

```cpp
ArrayCollection<float, 2, 3> floatArrays {
    {-10.f}, {2.f, 3.14f}
};

// results to
SomeType arraysCollectionData[] = {
    {-10.f, 0.f}, {2.f, 3.14f, 0.f}
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Can anyone provide guidance or an example of how to implement such a template class in C++ that is `constexpr` compatible and allows for instantiation in the specified manner?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Legacy C-arrays are never of variable size. Even if you provide a different number of initializers per-row, they are all of the same length with the unmentioned ones being default-initialized.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The resulting data could be anything, a vector an array, a list (but I would not prefer that) or whatever not just limited to C-arrays.

Comment: So why specify sizes at all? Wouldn't `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` work with the initializers you have in mind?

Comment: @Bondrewd *"The resulting data could be anything, a **vector**..."* Note that then it can't be initialized at compile time.

Comment: And there's that too

Comment: @user12002570 that's why I'm asking, I don't know where to start here

Comment: Variable length data sounds like dynamic allocation. And while some dynamic allocations are possible during compile time, there is currently no way to have these allocations "survive" until runtime. For example, a `std::vector` created at compile time inside a constexpr function, will also have to be destroyed at compile time.

Comment: *"In this example, `myArrays` should contain arrays of different sizes"* -- You have a concrete example, so why not give a concrete explanation? Do you mean that in this example, `myArrays` would contain four arrays of `int`, where the first array has size `3`, the second `6`, the third `8`, and the fourth `2`? More generally, the first template parameter is the type of data, while the remaining parameters give the size of each array, in order (the number of arrays is the number of numerical template parameters)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get by with an alias to a tuple of arrays, assuming you don't have other unspecified requirements.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template<typename T, unsigned ...Sizes>
using ArraysCollection = std::tuple<std::array<T, Sizes>...>;

constexpr ArraysCollection<float, 2, 3> floatArrays {
    {-10.f}, {2.f, 3.14f}
};
```

Both those types are constexpr friendly in the latest C++ standards, and so you can use them for constant initialized objects just fine.

Comment: Nitpick: second argument to `std::array` is `std::size_t`, not `unsigned`.

Comment: @Quimby - It's unlikely than an `unsigned` won't convert to a `std::size_t`. So for simplicity of presentation, I'll keep the parameters of `ArraysCollection` as they are.

Comment: An alternative if one would like to expand the functionality of `ArraysCollection` could be inheritance: `template <class T, T... Ss> struct ArraysCollection : public std::array<T, Ss>... {};`

Comment: @TedLyngmo - It's not quite as straight forward. Even if you don't mind writing a bunch of machinery yourself for iteration, you can't have sizes repeat in this scheme, because then you'd inherit directly more than once from the same base class, which is ill-formed. Did you mean to inherit from the tuple?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah, yes, that'd be it. Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MoxdK5fqv) perhaps.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: But now copy-elision is just not getting an intuitive syntax.